# Count issue with Rails, rspec, transactions & change block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

After upgrading from Rails 5 to 6 I noticed that tests which are using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` started failing within rspec change blocks.

Code below raises the error even though it shouldn't (IMO). It looks like ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute uses different transaction than standard ActiveRecord queries.

```
expect {
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO users (...) VALUES(...)")
  raise "Transaction issue!" if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from users").count != User.count
}.to change {
  User.count
}
```

Any idea why and how to fix/address this properly?

*p.s. If I run the test in a single file (`rspec spec/single_test_spect.rb`) it works - test fails only if all tests in the suit are being run.*

Comment: As a point of future proofing don't use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`. Use the connection off whatever model you are using. That saves you from having to refactor all over the place if you ever go multi-db. Not even sure why you would use it from a test in the first place though - I mean what DB queries are you doing from your test that can't be written with the query interface?

Comment: I used this simple example in order to illustrate the problem. In real world, we have advanced insert query (optimised for batch insert/update operations) which was part of one service. 
I tried to show an example where it is obvisou that 2 queries are run on 2 different transactions. I also noticed that this problem occurs only within expect blocks. If I refactor the test so it doesn't use blocks - everything works :(